# Removing white background from raster as well as cleaning up edges?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, geotiff-tiff

I am looking to remove white background from a tiff as well as cleaning up the edges. I have used display background values from the symbology tab as well as applying gamma stretch for edges.. I can not seem to do both at the same time..

I am using ArcMap.

I have a raster that has a white background, which I can remove, but leaves jagged white/black edges.

I am trying to remove for a better visual.

[image]

It is a multiband tiff. It was derived from drone photogrammetry software.

Comment: Please provide some more information. First of all: Which software do you use? See [How to ask good questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also, how do you want to "remove" the white background : making it black or transparent ? is it a single band or multiband tiff ? does your white background have a specific value

Answer (score 1):

The blocky noise around the borders looks like the image was compressed with a lossy method. The lossy compression is especially hard on sharp boundaries and white spaces, introducing slight color variations that ArcGIS isn't seeing as white when you tell it to remove the white background.

Ensure that *both* your TIFF and the pyramids are compressed with a non-lossy algorithm like LZW instead of JPG or not compressed at all. I overlay a lot of imagery and 90% of the time it is the pyramid compression that causes this. ArcGIS defaults to lossy compression of the pyramids, so this problem manifests itself easily.